# Initialise output directory in TestNG custom report

Tags: java, testng

We can customise `TestNG` report by implementing `IReporter` interface and overriding

```
generateReport(java.util.List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, java.util.List<ISuite> suites, java.lang.String outputDirectory)
```

method. How can we initialise the `outputDirectory`. I can't find any documentation for that.

Note: I am not running TestNG programically. My question is how to configure `outputDirectory` in `testng.xml`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set output directory of TestNG before test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027610/set-output-directory-of-testng-before-test)

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: No @VimalrajSelvam

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by using object injection mechanism provided by testng methods. Use any of the configuration methods like this:

```
@BeforeSuite
public void setupBeforeSuite(ITestContext context) {
    TestRunner testRunner = (TestRunner) context;
    testRunner.setOutputDirectory("path to your desired location");
}
```